# ArangoDB: performance index in array element

Tags: performance, indexing, arangodb

I have a Collection in ArangoDB populated with element like this:

```
{

  "id": "XXXXXXXX",
  "relation": [
    {
      "AAAAA": "AAAAA",
    },
    {
      "BBBB": "BBBBBB",
      "field": {
        "v1": 0,
        "v2": 0,
        "v3": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "CCCC": "CCCC",
      "field": {
        "v1": 0,
        "v2": 1,
        "v3": 2
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to return only elements that have `field.v1 > 0` (or a combination of v values).
I've tried to write an AQL query like this one, but it doesn't use indexes and it is so slow with 200000+ elements.

```
FOR a in X
    FILTER LENGTH(a.relation) > 0
    LET relation =  a.relation
    FOR r in relation
        FILTER r.field > null 
        FILTER r.field.v1 > 0
return a
```

I've tried to create these indexes:

- `full text on relation[*]field`
- `skip list on relation[*]field`
- `hash on relation[*]field`
  but with no result.

What can I do? Can you suggest me any changes to the query?

Thanks.

Best regards,

Daniele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following changes, but they won't speed up the query noticeably:

- the filters `FILTER r.field > null` and `FILTER r.field.v1 > 0` are redundant. You can just use the latter `FILTER r.field.v1 > 0` and omit the other filter condition
- the auxiliary variable `LET relation = a.relation` is defined after `a.relation` is used in the `LENGTH(a.relation)` calculation. If the auxiliary variable would be defined before the `LENGTH()` calculation, it could be used inside it like this: `LET relation = a.relation FILTER LENGTH(relation) > 0`. This will save a bit of processing time
- the original query checks each `v1` value and may return each document multiple times if multiple `v1` values in a document satisfy the filter condition. That means the original query may return more documents than there are actually present in the collection. If that's not desired, I suggest using a subquery (see below)

When applying the above modifications to the original query, this is what I came up with:

```
FOR a IN X 
  LET relation = a.relation
  FILTER LENGTH(relation) > 0 
  LET s = (
    FOR r IN relation
      FILTER r.field.v1 > 0 
      LIMIT 1 
      RETURN 1
  )
  FILTER LENGTH(s) > 0 
  RETURN a
```

As I said this probably won't improve performance greatly, however, you may get a different (potentially the desired) result from the query, i.e. less documents if multiple `v1` in a document satisfy the filter condition.

Regarding indexes: fulltext and hash indexes will not help here as they support only equality comparisons, but the query's filter conditions is a *greater than*. The only index type that could be beneficial here in general would be the skiplist index. However, indexing array values is not supported in 2.7 at all, so indexing `relation[*].field` won't help and still no index will be used as you reported.

ArangoDB 2.8 will be the first version that supports indexing individual array values, and there you could create an index on `relation[*].field.v1`.

Still the query in 2.8 won't use that index because the array indexes are only used for the `IN` comparison operator. They cannot be used with a `>` as in the query. Additionally, when writing the filter condition as `FILTER r[*].field.v1 > 0`, this would evaluate to `FILTER [null, 0, 0] > 0` for the example document above, which will not produce the desired results.

What could help here is a comparison operator modificator (working title) that could tell the operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=` to run the comparison on all members of its left operand. There could be `ALL` and `ANY` modifications, so that the filter condition could be written as simply `FILTER a.relation[*].field.v1 ANY > 0`. But please note that this is not an existing feature yet, but only my quick draft for how this could be fixed in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much stj!

I'm waiting definitely for the new 2.8 version, with the improvement of array indexing.

Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Fulltext indes currently can only be used with [the FULLTEXT() function](https://docs.arangodb.com/IndexHandling/Fulltext.html).

Its currently not possible to use indices for determining the length of sub objects. This would be somthing one could solve using [function defined indices](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1501) once they would become real.

Right now the only way to get a useable performance for this would be to to remeber that length on another attribute while writing the documents into the collection:

```
{
  "id": "XXXXXXXX",
  "length": 6,
  "relation": [
    {
      "AAAAA": "AAAAA",
    },
    {
      "BBBB": "BBBBBB",
      "field": {
        "v1": 0,
        "v2": 0,
        "v3": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "CCCC": "CCCC",
      "field": {
        "v1": 0,
        "v2": 1,
        "v3": 2
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

<Clippy>[you look like you want to be using graph features for your data layout?](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html) </Clippy>

Comment: The problem is about the filter 'field.v1 > 0', not about the length of the array. I can't lookup on the field without performance issue. 

Thanks

Comment: You have to be able to filter on something indexeable in the outer `FOR` so the inner `FOR` gets a preselected subset. Else the query will always end up being a full table scan. You probably already tried to use [explain to revalidate whether the Indexes are used](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/Optimizer.html)?